# Getting error while implementing angular-calendar code of stackblitz

Tags: angular

I have implemented code of angular calendar in my project mentioned in link - https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink.

The code is running fine in Stackblitz but when I copied the same code in my project, I am getting following error at this line:

@ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true }) modalContent: TemplateRef;

Error message is as follow-

Argument of type '{ static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'static' does not exist in type '{ read?: any; }'

Can anyone please suggest how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove { static: true } if you are running angular version < 8

It would be just:

```
  @ViewChild('modalContent') modalContent: TemplateRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `static` option was only added in Angular 8. The error means that Stackblitz is using the most recent version of Angular while in your project you use Angular <= 7.

Either update your Angular version or remove the `static` field.